# Delete app from OSX simulator in Xcode

Tags: xcode, macos, simulator

How do i delete an app from the OSX simulator like on the iOS simulator??
I want to delete an app due to the change of Core Data xcdatamodeld but i can't find a way.
Thanks in advance

Comment: When you run an OSX app in Xcode doesn't it use a simulator?Actually i don't know i thought it was like for iOS :) but anyway how do i delete the app to "rebuild" it as the first time?

Comment: No, it runs it. Usually it's in the Build directory. You can either do a clean build or find it in the Organiser and delete it from there.

Comment: i managed to solve it by looking in the directory ~/Library/Application Support/ and deleting the .storedata file

Answer (score 15):

For macOS Monterey and Big Sur, the location links to the devices folder location:

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/{device_uuid}/data/Containers/Data/Application/

On MacOS Mojave 10.14.4 the folder is in the following location:

> ~/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.yourapp/

Comment: Couldn't find it in Big Sur. I mean container folder itself doesn't exist

Comment: @user4150758 I've updated the answer for Big Sur as well.

Answer (score 14):

As playitgreen mentioned in one of the comments, the way to delete data relating to your OSX app is by removing the folder/.storedata file from:

`~/Library/Application Support/<YOUR OSX APP BUNDLE NAME>/`

for example:

```
~/Library/Application Support/com.yourcompany.yourapp/
```

All credit to playitgreen

Comment: The next time I ran my app, it crashed on startup. I fixed this by doing a Product > Clean.

Comment: I ran in XCode 6.4 and didn't find that. I guess the best way to find the app is to Command+Click the app icon on dock, it will open up the location of the app. (Product>Clean also removes it).

Comment: @SunilChauhan Should be the correct solution - Easy to remember and fast

Answer (score 8):

Specifically for Catalyst apps in macOS 10.15 (Catalina) and Xcode 11.2.1.

I tried right-clicking on the app's icon in the dock and then Options -> Show in Finder. I deleted all the files there and ran again from Xcode. The files returned and the app still had the data from before.

In `~/Library/Containers` I found a folder called `maccatalyst.<my_apps_bundle_identifier>`. I deleted the files contained there and when I reran the app from Xcode the files returned and original data was gone. So that seems to be the way.

`~/Library/Containers/maccatalyst.<app_bundle_identifier>`

Comment: It seams like the maccatalyst prefix has been removed in Xcode 12. I found my Catalyst  app files at `~/Library/Containers/<app_bundle_identifier>`

Comment: The path to my app folder was `~/Library/Containers/$(PRODUCT_NAME)`. Also worth to mention that `$(PRODUCT_NAME)` was localized.

Answer (score -5):

There are 2 solution:

1. When running the app press <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+ <kbd>H</kbd> (simulates a home button press), then you can remove it by long press like on the phone
2. Remove the appropriate app foler from `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/<ios_version_that_you_use>`