# Uninstall macOS app

Tags: xcode, macos, uninstallation

I am testing my macOS app, and I need to uninstall it to check some special features. For iOS apps this is very simple, I simple remove the app from the simulator and then I reinstall it. How can I do the same thing for macOS?

I've already tried to delete the app from `/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug/myapp.app`

But that doesn't work. If I run my project again, all previous settings and saves are kept.

How can I completely remove an app made in Xcode for macOS development?

The topic: [Delete app from OSX simulator in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590285/delete-app-from-osx-simulator-in-xcode) didn't help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete app from OSX simulator in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22590285/delete-app-from-osx-simulator-in-xcode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many apps that allow you to thoroughly uninstall apps, for example [AppCleaner](https://freemacsoft.net/appcleaner/). However I'd try to use the *clean build folder* option within Xcode first.

Comment: AppCleaner did help me.

Answer (score 5):

This command will delete whatever's in the `UserDefaults` database for your app:

```
defaults delete com.mywebsite.myapp
```

Replace `com.mywebsite.myapp` with the bundle ID of your application.

If you have items other than just `UserDefaults` settings, they'll appear in the `home/Library/Containers` folder in a folder named after your app bundle (assuming your app is sandboxed; otherwise check `home/Library/Application Support`). You'll find the plist file for your `UserDefaults` in here as well, although deleting that using the Finder isn't reliable, since the system sometimes caches the plists in memory, so the `defaults` command is still the best way to clear that.